# How can I do performance profiler on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce

I am using WordPress WOOF - [WooCommerce Products Filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) on more than 24k product ecommerce site. This plugin is making my site speed critically low. Is there any plugin so I can know the specific query and it's run time?

And also could you please tell me how do I boost website speed by optimizing database query

I have tried using p3 performance profiler and didn't got a luck on that.Please find the attached file for overall queries performance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y3nk.jpg)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried w3 Total Cache?

Comment: Hi Ahmed,

Thanks for your assistance. I am using super cache plugin for this but still page load time is more than 22sec.Here is my website: http://lagers.proshore.be/

Comment: somehow I solved page load time with WooCommerce Products Filter plugin using transient. I had overwrite woof_print_tax() function  woocommerce-products-filter/views/woof.php in theme function file.

Here at the moment I am using this plugin to filter product through custom taxonomy.- inner, outer, width, weight. And it is on select dropdown. 
I replace `<?php
   echo $WOOF->render_html(WOOF_PATH . 'views/html_types/select.php', $args);
   ?>` with following code:

Comment: `if( $args['taxonomy_info']->name == 'inner' ) {

       if ( false === ( $woof_filter_transient = get_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_inner' ) ) ) {
           // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $sfc_woof_filter_transient_inner = $WOOF->render_html(WOOF_PATH . 'views/html_types/select.php', $args);
            set_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_inner', $sfc_woof_filter_transient_inner, 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            
       }
       echo $woof_filter_transient;
      } elseif( $args['taxonomy_info']->name == 'outer' ) {`

Comment: `if ( false === ( $woof_filter_transient = get_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_outer' ) ) ) {
           // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $sfc_woof_filter_transient_outer = $WOOF->render_html(WOOF_PATH . 'views/html_types/select.php', $args);
            set_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_outer', $sfc_woof_filter_transient_outer, 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            echo $woof_filter_transient;
       }
       echo $woof_filter_transient;
      } elseif( $args['taxonomy_info']->name == 'width'  ) {`

Comment: `if ( false === ( $woof_filter_transient = get_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_width' ) ) ) {
           // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $sfc_woof_filter_transient_width = $WOOF->render_html(WOOF_PATH . 'views/html_types/select.php', $args);
            set_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_width', $sfc_woof_filter_transient_width, 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            echo $woof_filter_transient;
       }
       echo $woof_filter_transient;`

Comment: `} elseif( $args['taxonomy_info']->name == 'weight' ) {
       if ( false === ( $woof_filter_transient = get_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_weight' ) ) ) {
           // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $sfc_woof_filter_transient_weight = $WOOF->render_html(WOOF_PATH . 'views/html_types/select.php', $args);
            set_transient( 'sfc_woof_filter_transient_weight', $sfc_woof_filter_transient_weight, 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            echo $woof_filter_transient;
       }
       echo $woof_filter_transient;
      }`